How to get the signature hash without simulation (skipPreflight) when sending Transaction with 2 quotes on Jupiter
Hello guys i'm lost really how in my code can i get the signature hash without simulation ?
This is what i do for 2 quotes:
Where to add : skipPreflight: true ??

POST /swap-instructions x2

    Promise.all([inQuote.json(), outQuote.json()]).then(
        async ([inQuote, outQuote]) => {
          // console.log(inQuote);
          // console.log(outQuote);

          const addressLookupTableAccounts = [];

          addressLookupTableAccounts.push(
            ...(await getAddressLookupTableAccounts(
              inQuote.addressLookupTableAddresses
            )),
            ...(await getAddressLookupTableAccounts(
              outQuote.addressLookupTableAddresses
            ))
          );

          const blockhash = (await CONNECTION.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
          const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
            payerKey: keypair.publicKey,
            recentBlockhash: blockhash,
            instructions: [
              ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
                units: 3000000, // Set a higher limit, adjust as needed
              }),
              ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
                microLamports: 1,
              }),
              ...inQuote.setupInstructions.map(deserializeInstruction),
              deserializeInstruction(inQuote.swapInstruction),
              deserializeInstruction(outQuote.swapInstruction),
              deserializeInstruction(outQuote.cleanupInstruction)
            ],
          }).compileToV0Message(addressLookupTableAccounts);
          const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

          // Sign the transaction
          transaction.sign([keypair.payer]);
          try {
            // Send the transaction
            const signature = await CONNECTION.sendTransaction(transaction);
            console.log("Transaction sent with signature:", signature);

            // Wait for confirmation
            const confirmation = await CONNECTION.confirmTransaction(signature);
            console.log("Transaction confirmed:", confirmation);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error sending transaction:", error);
          }

But i another case when i only send 1 quote
This is what i do :

POST /swap

    const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64');
    
    var transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);
    
    transaction.sign([wallet.payer]);
    
    const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize()
    
    const txid = await connections.primary.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
      skipPreflight: true,
      maxRetries: 10
    });
    console.log(txid);


So i'm seaching how to mix theses 2 codes to finnaly send a Tx with 2 quotes without simulation ...

When sending with 2 quotes :
Change :
 // Send the transaction
const signature = await CONNECTION.sendTransaction(transaction);
console.log("Transaction sent with signature:", signature);

// Wait for confirmation
const confirmation = await CONNECTION.confirmTransaction(signature);
console.log("Transaction confirmed:", confirmation);

To :
const signature = await CONNECTION.sendTransaction(transaction, {
    skipPreflight: true,
    maxRetries: 0
});

Will give the signature without verification
